# jQuery custom plugin - setting private options for multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

**Hi folks!**

I'm currently developing a client project where I saw myself doing the same javascript code over and over again. So I though it would be useful to wrap the logic inside a custom jQuery plugin. I've achieved it for a single instance of the plugin, but for multiple instances, I think I'm having a problem with the properties of each instance overwriting each other.

Well, let's get to the code! Here is the currently code that I have for the plugin:

```
// RESPONSIVE MENU ===========================//
// wrapper for a responsive menu plugin,      //
// made by Favolla Comunicação                //
//============================================//

/* INSTRUCTIONS
 Apply the plugin on the main wrapper of the responsive menu. For example:

 $(#menu).responsiveMenu($(#trigger));

 The plugin just toggles the classes, leaving the effects and layout for the css

 CONFIG
 - trigger: the selector of the button that will activate the menu (required)
 - activeClass: class name to be injectet when the toggle is activated (default: active)
 - submenuTrigger: the selector of the buttons that will activate the submenus, if the menu will have another levels (default: $('sub-toggle'))
 - submenu: the selector of the submenus (default: $('.submenu'))
 - submenuActiveClass: class name to be injected on the submenus when they are activated (default: open)
 - breakpoint: max window whidth where the plugin will work (default: 720)
 - timeOut: time in milissegundos to limite the onResize repeat. (default: 100)
 - moveCanvas: option to activate the "off canvas" pattern or not (just puts a class on the main elements of the page). (default: false)
 - canvas: class name of the elements that build the "canvas" (default: null)
*/

;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  $.fn.responsiveMenu = function(settings){

     var config = {
          'trigger': '',
          'activeClass': 'active',
          'submenuTrigger': $('.sub-toggle'),
          'submenu': false,
          'submenuActiveClass': 'open',
          'breakpoint': 720,
          'timeOut': 100,
          'moveCanvas': false,
          'canvas': '',
      };

      if (settings){$.extend(config, settings);}

      // plugin variables
      var mTrigger,
          menu = $(this),
          active = config.activeClass,
          button = config.trigger,
          bpoint = config.breakpoint,
          submTrigger = config.submenuTrigger,
          submenu = config.submenu,
          submenuActive = config.submenuActiveClass;
          canvasOn = config.moveCanvas;
          canvas = config.canvas;
          time = config.timeOut;

    return this.each(function () {

      if($(window).width() > bpoint){
        mTrigger = false;
      } else {
        mTrigger = true;
      }

      onChange = function(){

        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        var resizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){

          if($(window).width() > bpoint){
            mTrigger = false;
            menu.removeClass(active);
            button.removeClass(active);
            if(canvasOn){
              canvas.removeClass(active);
            }

          } else {
            mTrigger = true;
          }
        }, time);

      }

      $(window).bind('resize',onChange);
      $(document).ready(onChange);

      button.click(function(){
        if(mTrigger) {
          menu.toggleClass(active);
          button.toggleClass(active);
          if(canvasOn){
            canvas.toggleClass(active);
          }
        }
      });

      if(submenu){

        var submenuClass = '.' + submenu.prop('class');

        // toggle for the submenus
        submTrigger.click(function(){

          if(mTrigger) {

            if($(this).hasClass(active)){

              submTrigger.removeClass(active);
              submenu.removeClass(submenuActive);

            } else {
              submTrigger.removeClass(active);
              $(this).addClass(active);
              submenu.removeClass(submenuActive);
              $(this).next(submenuClass).addClass(submenuActive);
            }

          }

        }); 
      }

    });
  }
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

And then, when I want to apply the plugin, I make like this:

```
  $('#menu-wrapper').responsiveMenu({
    trigger: $('#nav-toggle'),
    submenu: $('.submenu'),
    submenuTrigger: $('.submenu-toggle'),
    moveCanvas: true,
    canvas: $('.canvas'),
    breakpoint: 862
  });

  $('#search').responsiveMenu({
    trigger: $('#search-toggle'),
    breakpoint: 862
  });
```

The main issue here is when I set to instances of the `responsiveMenu();`, it seems like some options are overwriting. For example, the first instance set `moveCanvas` to true, and it works, but when I leave it blank for the second instance (which leaves the `moveCanvas` option set to `false` for this element, this options for the first instance don't work anymore.

I know that maybe I'm not following the jQuery plugin best pratices, and I even read something about the [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/), which looks great, but I'm not an advanced javascript developer, so there a lot of things that I could do better, but I just don't now how to do.

Anyway, any help with this issue (and opinions about the plugin) will be very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> var mTrigger,
>     menu = $(this),
>     active = config.activeClass,
>     button = config.trigger,
>     bpoint = config.breakpoint,
>     submTrigger = config.submenuTrigger,
>     submenu = config.submenu,
> ```

Until here you were doing correct.

> ```
>     submenuActive = config.submenuActiveClass;
>     canvasOn = config.moveCanvas;
>     canvas = config.canvas;
>     time = config.timeOut;
> ```

Then, you introduced a semicolon - which leads to the further assignments (`canvasOn`, `canvas` and `time`) not being part of the [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) any more. They're no variable declarations, you assign to *global* variables here - and that way you overwrite the settings of the first plugin instance.

Change every but the last semicolon to commata.

Comment: Thank you, @Bergi! I'm feeling really dumb right now! The problem was not the code, but my lack of attention, such a simple detail that in my rush I didn't see. Thanks for clarify this issue and the result of it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate your settings in a class or closure and store them for each element the plugin is called on.

```
return this.each(function () {

    ...

    $(this).data('some-key', settings);

    ...

});
```

If you'd like to learn about jQuery plugin authoring, they have an article on it here http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and the tip about this article on jQuery authoring! However the @Bergi answer was more simple and pointed out what was wrong on my code!